# What causes fluctuations in cross-entropy loss?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am using the `Soft Max Algorithm` for the `CIFAR10` Data set and am having some questions regarding my cross-entropy loss graph. I managed to get an accuracy rate of 40% with the algorithm, so the accuracy is improving. The confusing part is interpreting the results from the cross entropy graph as it is not similar to any of other graphs I've seen online for similar problems. Was wondering if anyone could give some insight into how to interpret the following graphs. On the `y` is loss, on x is batch number. The two graphs are for batch size 1 and 100.

Batch size 1:
[image: Batch size 1]

Batch size 100:
[image: Batch size 100]

Answer (score 1):

### What causes these fluctuations:

A (mini)batch is just a small part of the CIFAR-10. Sometimes you pick easy examples, sometimes you pick hard ones. Or perhaps what seems easy is just difficult after the model has adjusted to the previous batch. Afterall, it is called **Stochastic** Gradient Descent. See e.g. the dicussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232056/how-could-stochastic-gradient-descent-save-time-comparing-to-standard-gradient-d/232058#232058).

### Interpreting those plots:

Batch size 100: It's clearly improving :-) I would recommend you take the mean of the cross entropy across the batch, rather than summing them.

Batch size 1: There seems to be some improvement for first ~40k steps. Then it's probably just oscillation. You need to [schedule the learning rate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzulmoOg2JE).

### Other related points:

Softmax is not an algorithm, but [a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) which turns a vector of arbitrary values into one that is non-negative and sums up to 1, thus is interpretable as probabilities.

Those plots are very clumsy. Try a scatter plot with small dotsize.

Plot accuracy together with the cross-entropy (on a different scale, with a coarser time resolution) to get a feeling for their relation.